How to more formally prove this inequality
This is a simple problem I came up with while doing another problem:
Given: $n < (n + \frac{1}{2}) < y < (n + 1)$
Prove: $|y - n| > |y - (n + 1)|$
So how I proved it was simply using the intuition from number line and tried to write it in more formulaic way:
$|y - n| = \frac{1}{2} + |y - (n + \frac{1}{2})|$, hence $|y - n| > \frac{1}{2}$  since I'm adding something > 0
$|(n+1) - (n+\frac{1}{2})| = \frac{1}{2} = |(n+1) - y| + |y - (n + \frac{1}{2})|
=> \frac{1}{2} - |y - (n + \frac{1}{2})| = |(n+1) - y|$,
hence $|(n+1) - y| < \frac{1}{2}$ since I'm subtracting something > 0
Hence $|y - n| > |y - (n + 1)|$.
Is this sufficient way of proving it? Could I have explained "... hence $|y - n| > \frac{1}{2}$  since I'm adding something > 0" more better/formally? Is there a more formal way of proving it, or is this the best it could be done in?

You can simplify the reasoning, getting rid of the absolute values, by noting that $|y-n|=y-n$ and $|y-(n+1)|=n+1-y.$ Then you only need to prove that $y-n>n+1-y$ which is equivalent to $2y > 2n+1$ and therefore to $y>n+1/2.$

So if they're equivalent actually trying to prove formally would be to start with y > n + 1/2 and then manipulate it in backwards way to get y - n > n + 1 - y, correct? I mean now that I think about it since each manipulation is an iff statement, then I guess it's fine to do this. Kindly if someone with better understanding of proofs than me could clarify this, I'd be grateful.

Yes, the algebraic manipulations without the absolute value signs would be equivalences. Then the final step would be to replace $y-n$ with $|y-n|$ and $n+1-y$ with $|y-(n+1)|$ using the given inequalities.
